# Get unique users from dataframe till the current date | pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follow:

```
UID     Date
101     20/12/2020
102     20/12/2020
102     20/12/2020
103     21/12/2020
104     21/12/2020
105     22/12/2020
101     22/12/2020
106     23/12/2020
107     23/12/2020
108     23/12/2020
```

On each date, there could be occurrences of any uid. I need to find the total unique users till now for each date.
e.g. The desired output is

```
Date            Unique users till now
20/12/2020      2
21/12/2020      4
22/12/2020      5
23/12/2020      8

Explanation:
20/12/2020: Total unique users till now 2 (101, 102)
21/12/2020: Total unique users till now 4 (101, 102, 103, 104)
22/12/2020: Total unique users till now 5 (101, 102, .., 105)
23/12/2020: Total unique users till now 8 (101, 102, .., 108)
```

On each day I need to find how many unique users have accumulated till now.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `drop_duplicates` to get rid of the repeated UIDs and only keep the instance on the date where we first encounter a specific UID. (e.g. this will ensure we only count UID 101 for the 20/12/2020 date, and not a second time at the 20/12/2020 date). From there, groupby your unique days and use `nunique` to get the unique ID's from that date. Lastly use `.cumsum` to get cumulative number of unique UIDs for each date:

```
out = (df.drop_duplicates("UID", keep="first")
         .groupby("Date")
         .nunique()
         .cumsum())

print(out)
            UID
Date
20/12/2020    2
21/12/2020    4
22/12/2020    5
23/12/2020    8
```